# Integer cannot be derefereneced

Tags: java, swing, increment

Wrong variable chosen on line **tenSecs.set text(Integer.to string(i++)**;

The following code allows me to initialise a timer and when it is started, it adds one to the display, oneSecs.

```
    javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       AddOneActionPerformed(evt);
   } 
});

private void StartStopTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

if (!tm.isRunning()) {
         tm.start();
    } else {
         tm.stop();
    }

        ScheduledExecutorService e= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); //Start new scheduled executor service to invoke a timer that start wehn button is pressed
        e.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Follow this Override to do task
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    //Override will let the task run                

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images\\" + TextGrabber() + ".png"));
                            oneSecs.setText( DigitValue.getText());

                            int i = 0;

                            if (Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText()) == i) {
                                tenSecs.setText(Integer.toString(i++));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //Update will be for every 100 milliseconds concurrent to system time
} 

// Variables declaration - do not modify   
private javax.swing.JTextField oneSecs;
private javax.swing.JTextField tenSecs;
// End of variables declaration
```

Comment: Please show us the declarations of `oneSecs` and `tensecs`.

Comment: they are both jTextfields, so they appear undeclared in the code (as far as I am aware) please do correct me as I am fairly new to java

Comment: You should always show the declarations of variables in your code samples, and you should always quote THE EXACT error message and indicate what line in your code is flagged by the message.

Comment: How is the code fake? Please take another look at the updated code

Comment: It was fake when you had `getText` instead of `setText`. I assumed that `tensecs` instead of `tenSecs` was another error made when retyping the code into the question, but if that's in your real code, then apparently you have a variable `int tensecs;` somewhere that you're not showing.

Comment: to use Swing Timer or ScheduledExecutorService, don't to mix that in event from Listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are using two very similarly-named variables in your program. One is `tenSecs`, whose declaration you've shown us, and the other is `tensecs`, which you haven't shown, and judging from the error, it is defined as `int`.

It is not a very good practice to use two different variables that are named so closely. Suppose you wanted to keep a variable that represents the integer value of `tenSecs`. Don't name that variable `tensecs`, `tenSECS` or `tenSecss` or anything like that. The difference is easy to overlook and finding an error like this is very hard. Use a name like `tenSecsIntValue` or something like that.

So, to fix the issue, simply replace that `tensecs` with `tenSecs` in your code.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for your input. I have noticed however that fixing that problem, leaves the tenSecs textfield at 0 and does not increment the value every time 0 is reached

Comment: Yes, but that's a different issue. This is because the value of `i` is local and it's set to zero just before setText(). So the `i++` is not really doing anything. That's a logical error on your part.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to help me correct my error?

Comment: It's really hard to do that, at the moment. Your code is not properly formatted, does not include the declarations that allow it to be compiled, and it's also not clear what you are trying to achieve, what oneSecs is supposed to do and what tenSecs is. Please add that information to your question. Also mention that the original problem was solved and use the updated code, of course. Then I - or someone else - will be able to help you better.